# Is there a way to dynamically sum diagonals in a table?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm attempting to sum all the cells diagonally from the corner of a cell within a table so if the cell is A1 i'd want it to show the sum of B2,C3,D4 etc. but dynamically expand with the table so if i added a Column E it would sum in E5 without it needing to be manually altered.

At the moment I am manually adding in the required cells when the table expands but is isn't sustainable. I've used a very reliable sumproduct equation to calculate the diagonal but I can't get it to maintain the required square matrix with table expansion or exclude the cell its being used in

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(Table1)-MAX(ROW(Table1))=COLUMN(Table1)-MAX(COLUMN(Table1)))*(Table1))
```

I can't work out how to remove the column and row of the cell that the formula is in from from the arrays and this only works for a square table and the top corner. Any other positions within the table return zero and attempts to hardcode and remove the rows which aren't required cause  #VALUE

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array formula. This is an example of the formula to use considering the first 3 rows and columns:

```
{=SUM(A1:C3*(ROWS(A1:C3)+1-ROW(A1:C3)=COLUMN(A1:C3)))}
```

In your case you can apply the formula to a large range. If your matrix expands it will include all values in the range, e.g. (for 100)

```
{=SUM(B2:CY100*(ROWS(B2:CY100)+1-ROW(B2:CY100)=COLUMN(B2:CY100)))}
```

Note:
For an array formula to work you will need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering it into the cell. The brackets {} will then be added automatically. You do not type these yourself.